# Developing a crush or infatuation

Tags: single-word-requests, phrasal-verbs

For "crush" in meaning:

> **2** *informal* a brief but intense infatuation for someone, especially someone unattainable

- What word would replace the terribly technical *developing* a crush?
- Does one only *get infatuated* or is there a less generic word than *get* to signify developing infatuation?

The particular sentence for which I need this is

> "Do you sometimes fall in love with a character from a book?”

I'm feeling "*love*" is too strong here. *Crush* or *infatuation* would both be better, but while you *fall in* love, what do you do with these two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatives to *"get"* include, for example, *"**become** infatuated"*, but I have to say if OP thinks *"develop a crush"* sounds too "technical", the options are probably somewhat limited.

Personally, I think *infatuation* sounds a bit extreme for how you might relate to fictional characters. I'd probably ask something like...

> "Do you sometime experience feelings of romantic attachment to a character in a book?"

Comment: While I agree in most cases this may sound a little extreme, you really don't want me to show you some more hopeless cases. (for risk of concussion-inducing facepalm...)

Comment: @SF.: Perhaps you need to provide more context! Seriously, I'm having trouble imagining a context in which you'd specifically want to distinguish between asking whether someone is *infatuated*, or simply *experiencing feelings of romantic attachment* to a fictional character. I suppose you could ask if they are *"obsessed"*, but who knows how the other person would classify their (manifestly pathological, imho) feelings? They might deny being *obsessed* because they think they're only *infatuated* (or vice-versa). With my version, they'd have to at least admit to *something*.

Comment: Heh, :) Perhaps it's my poor grasp of English that makes me believe given word has connotations it does not. :) Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @SF.: There may be a cultural difference too. Certainly when *Brits* need to ask what is effectively a highly personal question, we tend to "downplay" the extent of anything "abnormal", and often we use more formal words. For example, *"Do you experience discomfort when you pass water?"*, not *"Does it feel like molten lead when you piss?"* is how you'd "carefully" ask someone if they have a urinary tract infection! :)

Answer (score 4):

***"Get a crush"***

***"Get infatuated"***

***"Crush on"*** (a newer idiom used like "I'm crushing on you!")

***"Fall for"***

Comment: Members of the generation experiencing first crushes indeed use "crushing on".

Answer (score 2):

I checked on [Google books](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+crush+on%22&hl=en&lr=lang_en&safe=off&tbo=d&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1985,cd_max:2008,lr%3alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=5GzSUIDhMOmQ2gXw7ICABg&start=10&sa=N#q=%22a+crush+on%22&hl=en&lr=lang_en&safe=off&tbo=d&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1985,cd_max:2008,lr%3alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=f23SUNziIYiC2gXnoYHQDQ&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.b2I&fp=ad9807c32490cd9c&bpcl=40096503&biw=1201&bih=876), and these seemed to be by far the most common ways of expressing it with the word *crush*:

> - Have a crush on / has a crush on / had a crush on
> - Get a crush on / got a crush on
> - Develop / developed a crush on

All three of those were somewhat easy to find among the many pages of hits, but I didn't manage to find any other way the words *crush on* were used.  (I checked through at least 10 pages of the results, but all that talk about crushes started to bring up too many memories of junior high school, so I abandoned the search.)

Another term you can use for this is [***puppy love***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppy_love).